# Adding line items to cart in Ubercart 3 and Drupal 7

Tags: forms, ubercart

Is there a simple way to add line items to a user's **cart** in Ubercart 3 ?

I've been searching for a solution all day. I basically need to add additional service cost for certain items that may appear in a user's cart. I've defined this additional cost as a line item.

I know its possible to add line items to an *order*, however from what I understand cart contents become an order only after passing through checkout. But if I want this line item to appear on the cart page (where you have a list of items in the cart and the total cost etc) I can't use this method.

Currently I'm resorting to customising the cart table, which is a pain. Then later I plan to add the line item to the order.

There must be a better way to do this. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

(Also, I've been having problems getting `hook_uc_order` to work, is there a problem with this in D7?)

If somebody could point me in the right direction that would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.